# Issue with base converter function

Tags: c++

I'm helping a friend with a C++ assignment. There is an issue with the folowing base converter function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int strToInt(string num, unsigned base){
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<num.length(); i++) {
        if (num[i]>='0' && num[i]<='9')
            result += (num[i]-'0')*pow(base,num.length()-i-1);
        else if (num[i]>='A' && num[i]<='F')
            result += (num[i]-'A'+10)*pow(base,num.length()-i-1);
        else if (num[i]>='a' && num[i]<='f')
            result += (num[i]-'a'+10)*pow(base,num.length()-i-1);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    string number;
    int base;
    while(number.compare("exit")!=0){
        cin>>number;
        cin>>base;
        cout<<strToInt(number,base)<<"\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some inexplicable reason every time I enter 3 and 5 digit decimals and chose base 10 I am getting the proper number -1.

E.g.

```
100
10
99

10000
10
9999
```

I've been going over this function for the last 5-6 hours and adding all types of debug code, but for the good of me I can't figure out what the hell is wrong.

Code style remarks are also very appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: @latedeveloper good point about the magic number. Much more readable.
However I don't see any difference between == and compare().
What do you mean by testing the return value? Validation? That is not a requirement of the task.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? Debugger is **the** tool to use, when the code behaves incorrectly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce; with your input I get 100-10-100 and 10000-10-10000

Comment: Do you use some very old compiler? Or a target platform with software emulated floating point? First suspect would be the rounding of the pow return value to int, but this works fine for me.

Comment: I am using mingw that comes with CodeBlocks. Won't be surprised if it's quite old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::pow` does floating-point math. You're probably getting a round-off error somewhere. The usual way to accumulate values is to multiply and add each time through the loop:

```
result *= base;
result += ch - '0';
```

Comment: Yes, much more elegant solution, thanks!